# Are there simple procedures or fractals that "compute" prime numbers?

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers, computer-science, visualization

Prime numbers are often computed with very procedural, "artificial-looking" algorithms, such as consecutively checking divisors up to the square root, risking numbers in tables (sieves), and so on. Fibonacci numbers, on the other hands, can be "computed" from a very simple rewrite system:

```
axiom  : A
rules  : (A → AB), (B → A)
```

If you repeatedly apply the rules to the axiom, you get this sequence of strings:

```
n = 0 : A
n = 1 : AB
n = 2 : ABA
n = 3 : ABAAB
n = 4 : ABAABABA
n = 5 : ABAABABAABAAB
n = 6 : ABAABABAABAABABAABABA
n = 7 : ABAABABAABAABABAABABAABAABABAABAAB
```

And, if you count the length of each word, you get the sequence of Fibonacci numbers!

> Are there are similarly simple ways to generate prime numbers?

Comment: @mvw per the rules, from 1 (AB) to 2 (ABA), the A is replaced by AB, the B is replaced by A... AB + A == ABA.

Comment: The derivation $A\to AB\to ABB\to ABBB$ has length $4$, which is not element of the usual Fibonacci sequence.

Comment: This is in fact essentially the original way the Fibonacci numbers were described; B being a pair of rabbits just born, and A being a pair of rabbits mature enough to begin reproducing. In a month, a B changes into an A, while an A remains the same but additionally produces a new B.

Comment: Have you analysed the difference between a consecutive terms in the progression?

Answer (score 3):

Well, if by "fractal" you accept a more "visual" concept, there are examples of visual sieves of prime numbers, like the one devised by Yuri Matiyasevich and Boris Stechkin, this is an excerpt of their own explanation ([all credits to them, original source here](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~yumat/Journal/Sieve/Sieve.html), just written and shown here for the purpose of explaining the sieve):

> The straight line connecting points $(i^2,-i)$ and $(j^2,j)$ (lying on the parabola $x=y^2$) crosses the x-axis at the point with of abscissa $ij$. Thus, if we connect all such points for $i,j=2,3,...,$ then all composite numbers will be "crossed out" from the positive part of the axis of abscissas.

[image]

Comment: @EthanBolker thanks for the markdown, on weekends I write from a tablet and formatting Mathjax is a nightmare.

Comment: That is so interesting! Definitely the kind of answer I was looking for. I want more!

Comment: @TreeHaunter there is a primality test based on Fibonacci numbers, I think can be seen at the Wikipedia, so your example of Fibonacci could be indeed used to obtain the prime numbers with some extra manipulation. There is a "but" about that primality test: unfortunately, there exist Fibonacci pseudoprimes. But this idea is very close to your initial point about a rewrite system.

Answer (score 2):

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Computability&oldid=764908084#Power_of_pushdown_automata), the set of primes (represented as numerals in the usual fashion) can't be presented by a context-free grammar.

However, given the criterion on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_language), I'm nearly certain there is a context-sensitive grammar that gives primes.

In fact, I think I even have an idea of how to make a context-sensitive grammar whose production rules implement a sieve, although it's complicated enough that I'm not inclined to try to write it down.

Comment: Nice to know it is not possible with a context-free grammar, but couldn't we be more creative, explore other structures? Perhaps some cellular automata, rewrite rules on graphs not strings, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

A [FRACTRAN program that generates the primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FRACTRAN) can be seen as such a system.

Comment: Very nice example.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you consider simple.

Considering Hurkyl's link, which locates the problem of listing all prime numbers in the upper half of the Chomsky hierarchy, I would not consider the needed computational models as simple.